# Is the conf/play.plugins file still required in Play 2.1.x?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I haven't seen it documented anywhere officially, but it seems in Play 1 and 2 updating the `conf/play.plugins` file is a mandatory step to enable plugins.

E.g. as described in this [article](http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=464) from *objectify.be*

> Regardless of the implementation language, plugins are invoked
>   directly by Play once you have added them to the **conf/play.plugins**
>   file. This file isn’t created when you start a new application, so you
>   need to add it yourself. The syntax is :. For
>   example, to add the example plugin to your project, you would use
>
> ```
>  10000:be.objectify.example.MyExamplePlugin
> ```

Is that still required in Play 2.1.x?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[By looking to the source code](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Application.scala#L97), the manual creation of the `conf/play.plugins` is still required.